# Python / Flutter RSA Encryption: Ciphertext should be the same

Tags: python, flutter, dart, encryption, rsa

I want to implement an RSA encryption which compute the same result in both Python and Flutter.

I know that the PKCS1_OAEP padding will give a different result for the same encryption.

Is there a way to make both functions calculate the same RSA result?

Python Code:

```
def encrypt_rsa_python():
  publicKey = RSA.import_key(open("static/keys/public.pem", "rb").read())
  encrypter = PKCS1_OAEP.new(publicKey)

  y1 = encrypter.encrypt(b'1234')
```

Here is my Flutter (dart) Code:

```
enc.Encrypted asymmetricEncrypt2(String message, RSAPublicKey publicKey) {
  enc.Encrypter encrypter = enc.Encrypter(enc.RSA(
      publicKey: publicKey,
      encoding: enc.RSAEncoding.OAEP)); 
  enc.Encrypted msg = encrypter.encrypt(message);
  return msg;
}
```

I know, of course, that removing the padding makes the whole encryption more insecure, however this is not relevant for my case here.

Kind regards,
Bagheer4

Comment: Why do you need it to have the same result? With padding you won't have the same result even for the same program run twice with the same input due to the padding randomness.

Comment: As I mentioned, I already know this. I need the same result because I want to calculate another value with the help of this…and Compare them

Comment: No, OAEP (and PKCS#1 v1.5 padding) are both non-deterministic. [Textbook RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1449) is deterministic, therefore insecure, and thus not used in practice, which is why it is not supported by many libraries.

Comment: There is no way to disable the padding in the python version? Because I achieved to implement textbook RSA in Dart and my last goal is in python. So if anyone can show me a version how I can disable the padding in python, it would solve my problem

Comment: PyCryptodome does not support textbook RSA, you can verify this yourself in the documentation, s. [Features](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/features.html), sec. *Asymmetric ciphers*: only *RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5* and *RSAES-OAEP* are supported. In both cases the padding cannot be disabled, of course, since these variants just define the respective padding.

Comment: So you have to use a different library for textbook RSA. Alternatively, you can implement textbook RSA yourself, which is trivial (in particular with Python) since it is just modular exponentiation. For compatibility you only have to consider if your Dart implementation pads the ciphertext or decrypted plaintext with leading 0x00 values to the key size (as Java's SunJCE provider does, for example).